# Hive Shell Multiple Java Options

Tags: shell, hive

I am running a hive query through a shell script. I want to set certain hive configurations along with it using `hive -hiveconf`. However, I want to enter multiple java options like:

`hive -hiveconf set tez.am.java.opts=-option1 -option2`

Unfortunately the shell script takes -option2 as a shell command and it fails because it doesn't understand it. How can I list all of the java.opts I want to include in there? I tried using quotes but that didn't work. I also couldn't write multiple instances of `set tez.am.java.opts=`.

Comment: Try double quotes (")

Comment: Tried it, didn't work

Comment: Can you run the multiple sets as individual statements inside your script?

Answer (score 0):

Correct syntax is `hive -hiveconf variable="value"`
And when you use `hiveconf` namespace to pass variables you should address all variables like this: `${hiveconf:variable}` inside your script. It seems not exactly what you want to achieve.

Sometimes scripts are very big including tens of Java settings and SQL scripts.

The solution I would recommend is to prepare a file with set of parameters then call `source my_script_params.hql` inside your HQL script. You also can generate this script from a database before executing your HQL script.